# Calculating the pulse rate using sensors

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, sensors

I have really work on a final year project in 4th year computer science. I need to calculate the blood pressure level of a human in a real time and alert to him.

Do we have any sensors for Ardino or Resbrry PI boards.

I have search on [enter link description here](https://www.sparkfun.com/categories/146) but I have seen lots of sensors for heart rate but non of them for blood pressure.

Do you think is there any sensors available to get the blood pressures from ardino or rasberry PI ?

Answer (score 1):

You've got a BIG project ahead of you.  Automated blood pressure monitors are expensive medical devices, but I'll get you started.

Take a look at this link and think about the physical functions you must accomplish.

http://homepage.smc.edu/wissmann_paul/anatomy1/1bloodpressure.html

First, you have to build a pneumatic control system to inflate a blood pressure cuff and then slowly deflate it.

Second, you have to build an acoustic monitor to listen for the heartbeat below the cuff and a digital signal processing algorithm to detect the heartbeat.

For the first project look online for small pneumatic pumps and solenoid control valves.  You will control these with the Arduino and a power transistor to switch the power on and off.

For the second project you will need to build a microphone and amplify that.  You can find plenty of examples of microphones on the Arduino forum.  The trick part will be designing the DSP filter to identify heartbeats and then count them.  See Simon Monk's book, "Beyond Sketches" for an intro to DSP on the Arduino.

Get started and post some more and I'll check back to see if I can help on specific problems as you go forward.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions. Can we measure the human mind state using the heart beat sensors. Do you have any idea!